# Linux Kernel Linked List

Tags: c, linux, macros, linked-list, kernel

I'm trying to use the Linux Kernel Linked List implementation but I am unable to compile. I'm following these sources exactly with no results (http://www.roman10.net/linux-kernel-programminglinked-list/ and http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists)

The list.h Kernel Macro for LIST_HEAD_INIT is as follows:

```
#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }


struct Node {
int data;
struct list_head list;
};

struct Node mylinkedlist;
LIST_HEAD_INIT(&mylinkedlist.list);    

void add(){
struct Node first;
first.data = 1;
first.list = LIST_HEAD_INIT(first.list);
list_add_tail(&first->list, &mylinkedlist.list);
return 0;
}
```

I keep getting:
    "error: expected identifier or '(' before '{'"

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion as to what might be going on. Could we see where `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is defined?

Comment: Its defined outside of the function add() right above it. LIST_HEAD_INIT(&mylinkedlist.list). I'm under the impression that it's a Macro in list.h, correct?

Comment: Probably. What I wanted to see was the macro (not where it's used).

Comment: oh okay. @DennisMeng:
    #define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }

Comment: @Alex In the question description if possible.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means @ShafikYaghmour I'm new to C. Could you explain?

Comment: @Alex looks like I was mistaken.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `INIT_LIST_HEAD(&mylinkedlist.list);`, not what you have now.

Comment: @WhozCraig That didn't work either. Getting an error at compile time:

    error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token

Comment: Look at the error (please *show* the errors to help avoid incorrect answers) and specify which line it is on. You likely have an error on `first.list = LIST_HEAD_INIT(first.list)` now. That should have taken care of the first one. `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is an *initializer* macro, not an assignment-macro, per'se. If it is as I suspect, your second problem can be "fixed" with `struct Node first = { 1, LIST_HEAD_INIT(first.list)};` I may have an incorrect `&` in the first one, but I don't think so.

Comment: @WhozCraig The error is on the line where I made the change to INIT_LIST_HEAD. I also have an error now at first.data = 1; The compile says "expected '}' before ';' token"

Comment: Wait a minute. This is in global namespace. `INIT_LIST_HEAD` obviously won't work, as it is an inline function call. You *have to* use the initializer macro. Change the first one to `struct Node mylinkedlist = { 0, LIST_HEAD_INIT(mylinkedlist.list) };` and throw out the line I mentioned earlier. And *amend* your question please with updated source. Thx.

Comment: I got it to compile using `LIST_HEAD(mylinkedlist);` at the top of my file and `struct Node first = {1,LIST_HEAD_INIT(first.list)};` followed by `list_add_tail(&first.list, &mylinkedlist)`

Comment: I may be mistaken, but if you do that (the `LIST_HEAD(name)` usage) you may well need to ensure your list head is the *first* member of your structure, but it sounds like you're on the right track with the initializer macro usage now.

Comment: @WhozCraig OK, so using my syntax, getting the head of the list would look like: `mylinkedlist.next`?

Comment: Well I compiled, but when I tried to run the system call I got a kernel oops...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that wrong.
First, your should **LIST_HEAD(mylinkedlist)**, not **LIST_HEAD_INIT** nor **struct Node mylinkedlist.**
mylinkedlist should be a standalone head of kernel linked list struct, it's used to link all list_head.

Second, you should **INIT_LIST_HEAD(&first.list)**, this is the way to dynamically assignment; **LIST_HEAD_INIT** is used when structure is statically created at compile time.

Last, you should **list_add_tail(&first.list, &mylinkedlist)**.

so the complete code should be:

```
LIST_HEAD(mylinkedlist);

void add(){
  struct Node first;
  first.data = 1;
  INIT_LIST_HEAD(&first.list);
  list_add_tail(&first.list, &mylinkedlist);
}
```

this code work fine for me.
I suggest you read Linux Kernel Development chapter 6, it explain this very well.

Comment: I got an error at `error: void value not ignored as it out to be` at `struct Node first = {1, INIT_LIST_HEAD(&first.list)};`

Comment: Are you play another piece of code? if you are statically assign, use LIST_HEAD_INIT.

Comment: Adding link to the kernel-doc:  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/core-api/kernel-api.html#list-management-functions